# How do I web scrape this tag?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is my HTML tag. I am trying to get the value after the `<br>` tag. When I try to do it I get both the values. How would I do this using Beautiful Soup. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow">
<span style="color: #888888;"><strike>CDN$ 2.29</strike></span>
<br>CDN$ 1.48
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code.

Comment: `js_soup.find_all("div", class_="col search_discount responsive_secondrow")` - this returns both the values.

Comment: `js_soup.find_all("strike",)` - this returns the value inside strike .

Comment: But I need the value in `<br>`

Comment: maybe lxml and xpath could be an option. Beautifulsoup might not do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically had it, just needed to use the attrs dictionary for the correct div class and then searched for the next 'br' tag, whose sibling is your text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
HTML = """
<div class="col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow">
<span style="color: #888888;"><strike>CDN$ 2.29</strike></span>
<br>CDN$ 1.48
</div>
"""
soup = bs(HTML, 'html.parser')
# get all divs with your class attr
divs = soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class': 'col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow'})
for div in divs:
    # find the <br> tag, next_sibling is the data
    print(div.find_next('br').next_sibling)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html='''
<div class="col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow">
<span style="color: #888888;"><strike>CDN$ 2.29</strike></span>
<br>CDN$ 1.48
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
divs = doc.getElementsByClass('col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow')
for div in divs:
  value = div.br.nextText() # first
  print (value)
  value = doc.html[div.br._end:div._end-6] # second
  print (value)
  value = doc.removeHtml(div.getSectionByReg('<br.*>.*')) # third
  print (value)
  value = div.removeElement('span') # fourth
  print (value.text)
```

Result:

```
CDN$ 1.48
CDN$ 1.48
CDN$ 1.48
CDN$ 1.48
```